# Set <select> value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the value of a `<select>` with javascript here is my code

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var select = document.createElement("SELECT");

var option_mon = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_mon.value = "monday";
var monday = document.createTextNode("Monday");
var option_tue = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_tue.value = "tuesday";
var tuesday = document.createTextNode("Tuesday");

select.value = "tuesday";

option_mon.appendChild(monday);
option_tue.appendChild(tuesday);

select.appendChild(option_mon);
select.appendChild(option_tue);

div.appendChild(select);
```

But when I run this I dont see Tuesday as selected, Monday is selected as it is just the first value in the `<select>`, how can I set the value of the `<select>`

Comment: hi have you seen the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var select = document.createElement("SELECT");

var option_mon = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_mon.value = "monday";
var monday = document.createTextNode("Monday");
var option_tue = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_tue.value = "tuesday";
var tuesday = document.createTextNode("Tuesday");

select.value = "tuesday";

option_mon.appendChild(monday);
option_tue.appendChild(tuesday);

select.appendChild(option_mon);
select.appendChild(option_tue);
select.setAttribute('id', 'selectMe')

div.appendChild(select);
document.body.appendChild(select)
var e = document.getElementById("selectMe");
e.value = "tuesday";

function getvalue() {
    var e = document.getElementById("selectMe");

    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = strUser;
}

function setvalue() {
    var e = document.getElementById("selectMe");
    e.value = "monday";
    getvalue()
}
```

```html
<span id="p"></span><button onclick="setvalue()">set value</button><button  onclick="getvalue()">get value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
select.value = "tuesday";
```

After

```
select.appendChild(option_mon);
select.appendChild(option_tue);
```

As you should select the value after adding the `options` to the `select`.

Comment: Isn't that what the op is doing?

Comment: Ohh. crap. forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (After your last statement, set the value in the select)

```
div.appendChild(select);
select.value = "tuesday";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `select.value` **after** you added the options. Otherwise there is no option to select from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var select = document.createElement("SELECT");

var option_mon = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_mon.value = "monday";
var monday = document.createTextNode("Monday");
var option_tue = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_tue.value = "tuesday";
option_tue.selected = "selected";
var tuesday = document.createTextNode("Tuesday");

option_mon.appendChild(monday);
option_tue.appendChild(tuesday);

select.appendChild(option_mon);
select.appendChild(option_tue);

div.appendChild(select);
```

Untested but should work.

The key is:

```
option_tue.selected = "selected";
```

Because that's what I would do in HTML, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Add `select.value = "tuesday";` After `option_tue.appendChild(tuesday);` Make it Working.

Check you updated Working code:

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var select = document.createElement("SELECT");

var option_mon = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_mon.value = "monday";
var monday = document.createTextNode("Monday");
var option_tue = document.createElement("OPTION");
option_tue.value = "tuesday";
var tuesday = document.createTextNode("Tuesday");


option_mon.appendChild(monday);
option_tue.appendChild(tuesday);

select.appendChild(option_mon);
select.appendChild(option_tue);

select.value = "tuesday";

div.appendChild(select);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hst5zoo8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Put `select.value = "tuesday";` after appending option in select, then it should work.